# If-echo-else syntax error on form?

Tags: php, forms

I can't get a php contact form to work. All fields are complete and on 'Submit' I always get the 'else' statement (Error sending mail). I don't know much about php so I'm wondering if there's a syntax error on the if-echo-else lines??

This is the php code:

```
<?  
if($_POST['email']!='')
{
    $emailto="dgm102@hotmail.co.uk"; // change in this line
    $subject2="Contact Request";            
    $to2=$emailto;
    $mailcontent2="<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='800' border='0' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='0'>
      <tr>
        <td align='left'>
            <p>Hi,</p>
                  <strong style='color:#C59800'>New Contact Request has been sent with the below details.</strong><br /><br />
                  <strong>Name: </strong>".stripslashes($_POST['name'])."<br />
                  <strong>Email: </strong>".stripslashes($_POST['email'])."<br />
                  <strong>Message: </strong>".nl2br(stripslashes($_POST['message']))."<br />
            <p>Thanks</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
    //echo $to2;echo $subject2;echo $mailcontent2;
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!="yogs")
    {
        $headers2  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers2 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers2 .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
        $headers2 .= "From: ".stripslashes($_POST['email'])." <".stripslashes($_POST['email']).">" . "\r\n";    
        if(mail($to2,$subject2,$mailcontent2,$headers2))
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='thanks.html';</script>";
            exit;   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error sending email!";
        }
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "Please enter email address";
}   
?>
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Shirley Fire Department</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tinos:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="contact/contact.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico.png" />
</head>    

<body class="body">
<header class="mainheader">
    <img src="img/new-banner-small.JPG">
    <div class="header-flex">
    <h1>Shirley Volunteer Fire Department</h1>
    <div id="nav">
     <div id="nav_wrapper">
    <div id="drop-down-display"> <!-- ===DISPLAYS DROPDOWN MENU OVER CONTENT=== -->
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="department.html">DEPARTMENT<img src="img/dropdown-arrow.png"></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="department-meet-our-team.html">Active Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="apparatus.html">Apparatus</a></li>
        <li><a href="department-photo-gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="regs2.html">REGULATIONS</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- ===START MAIN=== -->
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <article>
        <p><span style="color:red"><strong>In case of emergency, call 911</strong></span></p>
            <p>The Shirley Fire Department is located at:<br />
                <strong>2795B Sheringham Point Road<br />
                Shirley V9Z 1G4<br />  
                    British Columbia</strong></p>
            <p>Phone (non-emergencies only): 250-646-2107</p>   
            <p>Click <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Shirley,+BC+V0S,+Canad%C3%A0/@48.3892994,-123.9032574,18z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x548f1bdc9ed6e3f7:0xcb47852af628b51a">here</a> to view a map of our location.</p>
            <p>You are welcome to visit us at the fire hall on Thursdays just before 7pm. Alternatively, fill in the contact form below and we will get in touch soon.</p></article>
<!-- ===FORM=== -->
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmcontact" id="frmcontact">
<!-- ===START FIELDS=== -->
<div class="fieldset">
<h2 class="contact-form">Contact Us</h2>
<div class="fields">
<p class="row">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="first-name" name="name" class="field-large" required="required" aria-required="true" /></p>   
<p class="row"><label>Email<span class="required">*</span>:</label><input type="email" required="required" aria-required="true" id="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@example.com" class="field-large" /></p>   
<p class="row"><label>Message:</label><textarea id="message" id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="5" class="field-large"/></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
        </div>
<!-- ===START ASIDE=== -->
<div class="aside-flex">
    <div id="aside-flex-img">
        <aside class="call-911">
        <img src="img/call911.png" alt="call911"/>
            </aside>
    <div id="aside-flex-volunteers">
        <aside class="volunteers">
<h2>VOLUNTEER FIREFIGHTERS NEEDED</h2>
<p>For more information <br>
    contact Chief <a href= "contact.html">Marty Gilbertson</a></p>
            </aside>
        </div>  
    </div>   
</div>
</div>
<!-- ===START FOOTER=== -->    
<footer class="mainfooter">
<p><small>Shirley Volunteer Fire Department. All Rights Reserved. Copyright 2015.</small></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a live link to the page in question:
[Contact form](http://shirleyfire.ca/contact.html)

Comment: Post the HTML to your form.

Comment: Edited original post

Comment: Just for the record, the problem was with my hosting provider, so there was nothing wrong with the script. They wouldn't allow the emails to be sent to an email address that wasn't registered with them. Sorted now.